# IS NULL doesnt find null rows in columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null, concatenation

```
$sql = $pdo->query('SELECT p.* FROM prospects p
        LEFT JOIN exported_leads e
        on p.id = e.lead_id WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), e.last_export_date) > 90 AND e.p". $partner_id ." IS NULL');
```

that is the query im using. this is how the db looks (with some examples):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX076.png

here's the structure of the db: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0EmL.png

as you can see, the row with export_id = 5 has a last_export_date of more than 90 days ago. so if i remove

```
AND e.p". $partner_id ." IS NULL')
```

from the query, it finds that row. however, if i still have it in and my column which im populating is p2. then you can see that the field is NULL. which means a IS NULL should work? however, when i run the query, it doesnt find that row.

whenever i import into that table i set all but one p* field to NULL automaticly. and you can see that it has NULL as value in the db.
i assume that the query doesnt see those values as NULL, so how could i improve this query to actually find those columns which says "NULL"?

Comment: If you echo out the SQL text (the string containing the SQL statement you are going to send to the database), you would spot the problem. It's not a problem with the query logic, it's a problem with string literals in your code. HINT: `$partner_id` isn't being evalauted in the context of your string literal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mess with concatenating & quotes :

```
$sql = $pdo->query('SELECT p.* 
                    FROM prospects p
                    LEFT JOIN exported_leads e ON p.id = e.lead_id
                    WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), e.last_export_date) > 90 
                      AND e.p' . $partner_id . ' IS NULL');
```

Comment: is the query really that sensitive to the mix of " and '? or did you change something else? because now it works and i cant see why and i wanna learn from this

Comment: @Sharpie: It is not a query, it is about invalid php code, as you begin declaring a string with `'` single quotes and finish with `"` double quotes.

Comment: @Sharpie : Have you succeeded?

Comment: yeah it worked. but im still trying to figure out what you meant. since only $partner_id is encased in "". and in some of my queries it starts with " and have ' in it and if i change them to " it crashes. but i didnt accept your answer because i couldnt. timelimit

Comment: @Sharpie : You can declare your strings like this `$string = "<...>"` or `$string = '<...>'` or `$string = "<...>" . "<...>"` or `$string = '<...>' . '<...>'`, but you can't mix them like you did : `$string = '<...>" . "<...>'`. You start with `'` or `"` and you end `'` or `"`, _accordingly_.